# Syntax of macro definition "0000"

Tags: c, sdk, macros, xilinx

I am working with a Xilinx chip when I came across this syntax in the Xilinx SDK (which is in C):

```
#define XSK_EFUSEPS_PPK0_HASH   "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

From the user guide it seems to specify that the value "0000 ... 0000" seems to denote the number of bits (which in this case, should be 384-bits) for AES. What exactly in this syntax and how does a macro specify the number of bits as opposed to a constant?

Comment: `XSK_EFUSEPS_PPK0_HASH` can be used to set all bytes of a hash buffer to `'0'` with `char hash_buffer[] = XSK_EFUSEPS_PPK0_HASH;`.

Answer (score 0):

[Presumably this link is the user guide you refer to?](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_4/oslib_rm.pdf)

In which case [this is the associated header file.](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/lib/sw_services/xilskey/examples/xilskey_efuseps_zynqmp_input.h)

where they say as a comment

```
/*
* ...
*   The value mentioned in this will be converted to hex buffer and written
*   into the ZynqMP Ps eFUSE array when write API used. This value should
*   be given in string format. It should be 96 or 64 characters long, valid
*   characters are 0-9,a-f,A-F. Any other character is considered as invalid
*   string and will not burn PPK0 hash.
*...
*/
```

The comment in the linked user guide is identical.

They explicitly say this is supposed to be a 96 or 64 character string (96 in your example). This has nothing to do with a bit count.

Further, [if this is the associated c file](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/lib/sw_services/xilskey/examples/xilskey_efuseps_zynqmp_example.c), then usage is as follows:

```
PsStatus = XilSKey_Efuse_ValidateKey(
                (char *)XSK_EFUSEPS_PPK0_HASH,
                XSK_EFUSEPS_PPK_SHA3_HASH_STRING_LEN_96);
```

OR

```
XilSKey_Efuse_ConvertStringToHexBE(
                (char *)XSK_EFUSEPS_PPK0_HASH,
                &PsInstancePtr->Ppk0Hash[0],
                XSK_EFUSEPS_PPK_SHA3HASH_LEN_IN_BITS_384);
```

where it is made clear in the calls  (perhaps unneccesarily) the the two functions expect a pointer to a sequence of `char`, (which every literal string does decay to in C)